# Find a specific character in php

Tags: php

How to find a specific character a but not aa or ab from a string in php ?
I want to use this code

```
$c=strpos($a, 'a') === 0);
$cr=strpos($a, 'ar') === 0);
if ($c == true) {echo "This is c";}
else if ($cr == true) {echo "This is cr";}
```

but not this

```
$cr=strpos($a, 'ar') === 0);
$c=strpos($a, 'a') === 0);
if ($cr == true) {echo "This is cr"; }
else if ($c == true) {echo "This is c"; }
```

This also not working as desired

$c = strpos($a, 'a'); 
$cr = strpos($a, 'ar');

if (substr($a, $c+1, 1) != 'a') {echo "found a!"; } echo a
else if (substr($a, $c+1, 1) != 'ar') {echo "found ar!"; } this also echo a not ar

Comment: As much as I hate to say it, a regular expression (preg) would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Use a regex to do the job

Comment: `$c = strpos($a, 'a'); if (substr($a, $c+1, 1) != 'a') { found it! }
`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg-match)`("/(?<!a)a(?![ab])/",$a,$match,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)`

If this returns `1`, then there was an `a` that is not `aa` or `ab` (note the lookbehind is needed, because otherwise the second `a` in `aa` would match).

Furthermore, you can use `$match[0][1]` to see what position in the string your match was.

Comment: Doesn't this also work with a simple word boundary like `\ba\b`?

Comment: @sofl Not really. What if you want to match `ac`?